# npm install not creating a new package-lock.json

Tags: npm, npm-install, package-lock.json

I accidentally deleted my package-lock.json file. npm install is not generating a new one. How do I get npm to recreate this file.

Comment: what node version are you using?

Comment: @emil I am using v6.10.2

Comment: I think below 8.0, they use shrinkwrap.json instead of package-lock.json

Comment: @emil it originally created a package-lock.json and I don't have a shrinkwrap.json either. Never seen it before.

Comment: Also, `npm` only creates/updates the lock file when it modifies your `node_modules` folder, so in *theory* you could delete your `node_modules` folder, run `npm i` and it should regenerate the file for you

Comment: Yes. if you remove node_modules and reinstall with node version 8.0 above, you will see lock file.

Comment: @emil I just upgraded to v8.4.0 and ran npm install and it created the package-lock.json

Comment: @emil, a proper answer would go a long way to resolving this question.

Comment: For other people experiencing this problem: also ensure that .npmrc does not contain `package-lock=false`. This is another reason why `package-lock.json` might not exist.

Comment: **Check your `.gitignore`.** I accidentally had `package-lock.json` in the `.gitignore` somehow and because `package-lock.json` wasn't showing up in the `git status` it was throwing me off.

Comment: None of the solutions so far has worked for me. I use node v16.14.* . I am running this in a sub-package ( workspace ), but it should work regardless, because it has a local `package.json` in the subfolder that my current working directory is.

Answer (score 102):

There might be a file called `.npmrc` which can contain

```
package-lock=false
```

which will cause the package lock file to not be generated.

In theory you could also have turned on `npm config set package-lock false` globally (change to `true` to turn on again), but that's less likely to happen unintentionally.

Comment: Yep, this is it. Thanks for adding this as a proper answer.

Comment: What's the purpose of this? I'm working with a project that requires running `npm ci` which fails because there's no package-lock file - so why would the maintainers add this setting to npmrc?

Comment: @Matt Some people do not see the benefits of version lock files and thus hate the fact that it generates a new lock file each time that 'pollutes' their commits from their perspective.

Comment: Can this also be specified in package.json (without additional files). I mean, it's about package.json. It's a required file to install node packages...

Answer (score 54):

The package-lock.json file was introduced in npm v5, so the steps you need to take to regenerate package-lock.json depend on which version of npm you're using.

FYI. Let's verify what version of node and npm.

```
npm -v
```

prints: `x.x.x`

```
node -v
```

prints: `x.x.x`

I believe for package-lock.json is auto-generated if the 2 conditions
npm version > 5.x.x and node version > 7.x.x are met

Then, try the following steps depending on which version you have:

*npm v5+:*

Regenerate the package-lock.json by running `npm install`. You may also regenerate the file without actually downloading dependencies by using `npm install --package-lock-only`

*npm v4.x & earlier:*

1. Generate a npm-shrinkwrap.json by running `npm shrinkwrap`. This file has the same format as package-lock.json and achieves essentially the same purpose in earlier versions of npm (see https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json and https://docs.npmjs.com/files/shrinkwrap.json for detailed information on this point)
2. Rename the npm-shrinkwrap.json to package-lock.json

Comment: Node 8.9.1 and npm 6.4.0. Not generating package-lock.json on `npm install` here.

Comment: Ah, just learned from comments above that `.npmrc` could have `package-lock=false`, which our project happened to have.

Answer (score 17):

To resolve this issue I have tried below mentioned things and it worked for me :

Make sure your package-lock globally enabled, you can enable it using:

**npm config set package-lock true**

To make sure your .npmrc is not blocking the creation of package-lock file, set this to your .npmrc

**echo 'package-lock=true' >> .npmrc**

***note***: package-lock.json is automatically generated for any operations where npm modifies either the node_modules tree, or package.json for npm -v > 5.x.x.

check your npm version: **npm -v**

update your npm to latest version using:

**npm install -g npm@latest**

**npm i -g npm-upgrade**

@will

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are in the right folder in the command line (use `pwd` in Linux/macOS to get the current path you're in).

I've run `npm install` many times, just to find out later I was doing it in the wrong folder.

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing the same issue

I just removed the `package-lock=false` from .npmrc and now it is creating the lock file

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of @DavidMulder's answer

Comment: Duplicate of the real answer

Answer (score -2):

If your npm version is <5 you will have a `shrinkwrap.json` file created **when running npm install.**

Otherwise `package-lock` will be created on npm versions 5 and above.

Comment: It generates nothing after running `npm i` for me. Using node 6.12.2 npm 3.10.10

Comment: don't know if this depends that much on the npm version, since for my project we use version 14.xx and it still generated a `shrinkwrap.json` most probably some setting. But it's worth checking if there is such a file if you can't find the `package-lock.json`