# issue with package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, npm, linux-mint

I am using `Linux mint version 19.2` and working with `nodejs`. But I'm facing a problem related to `package-lock.json` file. While initiating the `npm` through `npm-init` and installing the packages`package-lock.json`, file is not created.

I don't know why? Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: it would be helpful to list the commands you're running. From what I remember, `npm install` would create the `package-lock.json` file and not `npm init` (which still is not `npm-init`).

Comment: Check nodejs version installed on the machine.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45866533/npm-install-not-creating-a-new-package-lock-json)

Comment: What exactly is your problem, if npm-init is working then all you need to do is complete the npm init prompts (The first prompt, as shown in your screen capture, asks you to enter a package name. You can just hit Enter to skip through the prompts and accept the default values if you are unsure of what information to provide)